# Random overlapping intervals

Tags: probability, distributions

How can I find an analytical expression $D(n,l,L)$ in the following problem?

I randomly drop $n$ "bars" of length $l$ into an interval $[0,L]$. The "bars" can overlap. I'd like to find the mean total length $D$ of interval $[0,L]$ occupied by at least one "bar".

In the "low-density" limit, the overlap should be negligible and $D = n\cdot l$. In the "high-density" limit, $D$ approaches $L$. But how can I get a general expression for $D$? That should be a quite fundamental statistical problem, but I couldn't find an explanatory solution in the forums.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the bars are dropped truly random (statistically independent) of each other.

[image: For easier understanding I drew an example case.]

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No, its not. you can calculate the mean occupied length easily with a computer by sampling, but the problem seems that fundamental that there must be a theoretical approach to solve it. Since my attempts all failed, I was just curious on how to do it.

Comment: What's your model for how the bars are "dropped" onto [0, L]?  Is it possible for them to stick out on the edges?  Edit:  your drawing and answer suggest it is.

Comment: Find probability $p(x)dx$ that a given $dx$ is NOT covered - which is an intersection $n$ i.i.d. events. Then expected length of an *uncovered* portion is simply $\int_0^L p(x)dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

|----------------||----------------|-----------------------------------|----------------||----------------|

$x_0 - l/2\ \ \ \ \ x_0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_0 + l/2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_0+L - l/2 \ \ \ \ x_0+L \ \ \ \ x_0 + L + l/2$

The probability of a point in $[x_0,x_0 + L]$ to be occupied by a single dropped bar is

$x \in [x_0, x_0 + l/2): \ P_{o} = \frac{1}{L}(x-x_0+l/2)$

$x \in [x_0 + l/2, x_0 + L - l/2]: \ P_{o} = \frac{l}{L}$

$x \in (x_0 + L - l/2, x_0 + L]: \ P_{o} = \frac{1}{L}(-x+x_0+l/2+L)$.

Correspondingly, the probability to be empty is $P_{e} = 1 - P_o$.
The probability that a given point is still empty after $n$ dropped bars is $P_e^{n}$, and to be occupied is

$P_{o,n} = 1 - (1-P_o)^n = 1- (1-\frac{nP_o}{n})^n \approx 1 - e^{-nP_o}$

for large $n$.

Then, the mean occupied length in $[x_0,x_0 + L]$ after $n$ random "bar drops" is

$\langle D \rangle = L\langle P_{o,n} \rangle = \int_{x_0}^{x_0+L} P_{o,n}dx$.

Comment: You're on the right track, but there are some signs that more care may be needed. Perhaps the most important concerns the fact that the events associated with any two points are not independent: what, then, justifies multiplying the probabilities?  I also believe your expression for $P_0$ is incorrect.  Consider, for instance, the case where $l=L=1$. From your drawing it appears you are assuming the left endpoint of the bar has a uniform distribution on the interval $[-l, L]=[-1,1]$. Consequently the chance that $0$ is covered is $1/2$, which is not equal to $l/L=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. You're right, I should have written that there is supposed to be zero correlation between the random "drawings". And you're also right, the above solution is valid only when the bars are not allowed to stick out. How could the problem be solved when we allow them to stick out?

Comment: My point is that even when the bars are dropped randomly and *independently*, for any given $x,y\in [0,L]$ the events "this bar covers point $x$" and "this same bar covers point $y$" are strongly interdependent. In particular, if $|x-y|\gt l$, they cannot happen simultaneously.  One way to handle this rigorously is to relate the probabilities to expectations.

Comment: I considered the boundary effects now. I get your point that the occupation of two different points in the interval is correlated, but I don't see how it would affect the solution.